# Int and Double in one array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, double

Is there a way to put an int and a Double in the same array. I want to have an array (`p1[]`) where the first (`p1[0]`) is an int and all the rest of the elements are doubles. Is this possible?

Comment: Why? Sounds more like a class to me than an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by having an array of objects that are superclasses of Integer/Double (as pointed out elsewhere).

However I would perhaps enforce type safety by implementing an object that has an `Integer` component plus an array of `Double`s, and store an array of these. The upside (despite the additional complexity) is that you'll have type safety and not have to cast the first element to an `Integer` whilst casting the remainder to `Double`s.

Comment: Or just use Map<Integer, Double[]>.

Answer (score 2):

You can have an array of `Object`s, in which case you can put Integer and Double objects in it. However, I doubt there might be a better way to store your data than an array.

EDIT: You should of course make it a `Number` array as Nikita suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If memory is very important, you might want to use long[] instead. You can store the "int" easily, but the "double" needs more work:

```
long x = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double value); 
double value = Double.longBitsToDouble(long x).
```

But maybe it's better to create a special class, and then shift the array index:

```
class Y {
    int x;
    double[] values;
}
```

Comment: actually, why not just use double[] all the way, and cast the first element?